# Grails criteria select when hasMany hasn't any elements

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I have the classes:

```
class Course{
   String name
   static hasMany = [
        studentGrades: StudentGrade
    ]
}

class StudentGrade{
    String name
    int grade
}
```

How can I make a criteria to get the courses without any student grade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `isEmpty` criterion method:

```
def c = Course.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    isEmpty("studentGrades")
}
```

See the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) for further informations.

Comment: I was triying to make a projection and a count, when it was much simplier! Thank you!

Comment: just a little addition, you dont have to use criteria, this works as well:

`def results = Course.where { isEmpty("studentGrades") }`