# Grails hasMany: find all master records with a child that matches a criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class, hibernate-criteria

I have this **Grails 2.0.3** project wherein there are two models `DomainA` and `DomainB` and both are related to each other by a `many-to-many` relationship in which `DomainB` is a child of `DomainA`.

```
class DomainA {
  // properties
  static hasMany = [domains: DomainB]
}

class DomainB {
  // properties
  static hasMany = [domains: DomainA]
  static belongsTo = [DomainA]
}
```

Given this kind of design, I want to query all `DomainB` wherein there is/are an instance(s) of `DomainA` following the query set to `DomainA`.

```
def domainsList = DomainA.createCriteria().list() {
   // other criterions for the other properties
}
DomainB.createCriteria().list() {
   inList("domains", domainsList)
   // other criterions for the other properties
}
```

When executing the code above, an error is prompt `ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Parameter #1 has not been set.` wherein the `Parameter #1` is prompt the the `domains` property name in the `inList` criterion.

Having this problem, is this possible to solve? How?

Comment: You have class `DomainA` defined twice.  Can you fix your question?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: I think `inList` might not be the right predicate for this: B.domains is a list, not a single DomainA, so it won't ever be member of a list consisting of DomainAs anyway, right?

Comment: I think `B.domains` is a Set not a List. In regard to member properties, I have searched a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429023/grails-criteria-select-when-hasmany-hasnt-any-elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [GORM guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html), look for "Querying associations". Let's rather try to do it all with a single query.

With new "where" query, it's

```
def query = DomainB.where {
  domains { someAField == 3 } && someBField == 8
}
```

or with `CriteriaBuilder`:

```
DomainB.withCriteria {
  domains { 
    eq 'someAField', 3 
  }
  eq 'someBField', 8
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use HQL:

```
def domainBsWithDomainAs = DomainB.executeQuery( 'SELECT DISTINCT b FROM DomainB b INNER JOIN b.domains a WHERE a IN(SELECT DISTINCT a FROM DomainA a)' )
```

Or with [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html):

```
def domainsList = DomainA.createCriteria().list() {
   // other criterions for the other properties
}
DomainB.createCriteria().list() {
   "in"("domains", domainsList) // Use "in" (including quotes) instead of inList.
   // other criterions for the other properties
}
```

Comment: I was planning to use HQL, but then is there any ways to solve this by using `HibernateCriteriaBuilder`?

Comment: Is that would be the case, that would only say there is no instance of `DomainA` in any record of `DomainB`. What if I would create a `HibernateCriteriaBuilder` to `DomainA` and use it to query in `DomainB`. Updated my question.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted.  You want to use the keyword `in`. You should read up on [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html), it give you examples and lists of keywords you can use.

Comment: Sorry for the change, but still it returns me the same error message. I've tried changing my database from `H2` to `MySQL` and `MSSQL`, still the same error. Is still feature supported by Grails or I am to result to HQL?